# Error: Access is denied when trying to create a virtual environment with virtualenv

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtual environment on my machine with the `virtualenv` configuration.

**1st step:** In the Windows command prompt window I typed the command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

So far okay, it was installed successfully.

**2nd Step:** I tried to create a virtual environment in the folder named `programaria` with the command:

```
virtualenv programaria
```

However, in this step after entering the command `virtualenv programaria`, there is output the error message:

> Access denied.

I also tried opening cmd as administrator and the problem persists.

```
C:\Users\Vilmara>pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\vilmara\appdata\local\pro
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\vilmara\appdata\local\
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\vilmara\appdata\l
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\vilmara\appdata\lo
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.2 in c:\users\vilmara\appdata\loc

C:\Users\Vilmara>virtualenv programaria
Acesso negado.
```

I need to build machine learning models to study and if I install the tools and libraries directly on the machine, it may interfere with the tools previously installed on my operating system such as Python version, libraries etc. To avoid this problem, as a good practice to start this new project I would like to set up a virtual environment, to create a separate instance in which I also control the configuration of tool versions needed for my studies to ensure an isolated environment for explorations.

Comment: What Python interpreter are you using?

Comment: Have you tried running cmd as admin? Also what is the python version, and can you please share the output of python —version here, cos this could very well be a path issue in system env variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening your prompt as an Administrator ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).